# Rails 3.1.0: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, encode, rails-postgresql

I'm using Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2 with PostgreSQL. I want to get data from huge files (~300mb) and put it in database.
Here i use transaction:

```
File.open("./public/data_to_parse/movies/movies.list").each do |line|
  if line.match(/\t/)
    title = line.scan(/^[^\t(]+/)[0]
    title = title.strip if title 
    year = line.scan(/[^\t]+$/)[0]
    year = year.strip if year
    movie = Movie.find_or_create(title, year)
    temp.push(movie) if movie
    if temp.size == 10000
      Movie.transaction do
        temp.each { |t| t.save }
      end    
       temp =[]
    end
  end
end
```

But i want to improve perfomance using mass insert whith raw SQL:

```
temp.push"(\'#{title}\', \'#{year}\')" if movie
  if temp.size == 10000
   sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, year) VALUES #{temp.join(", ")}" 
   Movie.connection.execute(sql)
   temp =[]
  end
end
```

But i have this error "incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8". When i'm using activerecord it's all ok.
Files contains characters such as German umlauts. I tried all from here  [Rails 3 - (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465816/rails-3-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit), but it doesn't help me.

Do you have any idea where it comes from ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Problem was in files encoding. They were in ISO_8859-1 and i converted it to UTF-8 via  iconv.

Comment: +1'ing the iconv here.  "iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 YOURFILE > YOURFILE2 && MV YOURFILE2 YOURFILE".  Also, just to add for Googlers - I encountered this with a downloaded JavaScript file.