# UTF-8 trouble in rails app when passing to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, activeadmin

I just passed my application in his production environment :

- debian
- nginx
- unicorn
- mysql

In development I use :

- mac osx 10.7.3
- webrick
- sqlite

I got an error when I go to a view with some UTF-8 chars :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):
    1: render renderer_for(:new)
  app/admin/projects.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have added this at the top of my file :

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

It make it work in my development environment but not in my production envirnoment, any idea ?

**EDIT**

The error come from here :

```
f.has_many :roles do |app_f|
  app_f.inputs do
    # if object has id we can destroy it
    if app_f.object.id
      app_f.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Supprimer l'utilisateur du projet"
    end
    app_f.input :user,      :include_blank => false, :label_method => :to_label
    app_f.input :role_name, :include_blank => false 
    #app_f.input :role_level, :label => 'Author type',  :as => :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => Role::role_list
  end
end
```

It doesn't change anything if I change the current locale.

**EDIT**

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.1.0
I have no view to show because I'm using the [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) DSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change **mysql** in my Gemfile by **mysql2**

And it work :)

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 Questions about your question have you seen this questions i hope the answers can help to solve your problem. :)

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286117/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465816/rails-3-incompatible-character-encodings-utf-8-and-ascii-8bit)

Comment: Is the line 122 the line with then label tag ? i think you got a problem with the special charakter > ' < (apostroph) test it remove your label tag.

Comment: No problem with this character, just a fuc***g problem with the mysql gem :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell which Ruby verison you use. And you have to show the view code.

Encoding management is hard, and Ruby/Rails is no exception.

There are some great articles by [Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/) and [JEG2](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) about encoding and how Rails does it.

Comment: I dont know why but the error line correspondig to a line without any string

Comment: There is no view code, i'm using ActiveAdmin and is internal DSL for my views. I solved my problem by change mysql to mysql2 in my gemfile

Comment: OK that makes sense since "mysql" is unable to hold encoding metadata, but mysql2 is. I remeber having read something about this kind of issue elsewhere.